# How do I specify the path to an mssql database on linux?

Tags: sql-server, docker, asp.net-core, archlinux

Written on Windows asp.net core project using localdb as a database. When deploying in Docker on linux, I realized that there is no localdb in linux.

Installed mssql-cli, mssql-server, and mssql-tools. Started the mssql server and created a database in the console.

Now I can't figure out how to specify the path to it in appsettings

appsettings.json =>

```
{
  "Jwt": {
    "Key": "SuperTopSecretKeyThatYouDoNotGiveOutEver!",
    "Issuer": "https://localhost:44395/",
    "Audience": "http://localhost:44395/",
    "ExpireTime": 30
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=aspnet-Web-36346D92-8752-42C1-B65D-BD9B147F95E8;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Please tell me how to get DefaultConnection or solve the problem with minimal time.

Comment: Please post the JSON in your screenshot into the question itself.